# The argument type Future<bool> cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I'm trying to create a Visiblity widget that displays if a user is on a Firebase database Array. Looks like this (members Array): [image]

As you can see, I have created a StreamBuilder that should return the Visibility widget if the current user's username is on this Array:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection('chats').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(!snapshot.hasData){

            }else {
              final chats = snapshot.data.documents;
              List<ChatCard> chatCards = [];
              for (var chat in chats) {
                final String nameOfChat = chat.data['name'];
                final String lastMessageSent = chat.data['lastMessageSent'];
                final List members = chat.data['members'];

                final ChatCard chatCard = ChatCard(
                  nameOfChat: nameOfChat ?? '',
                  lastMessageSent: lastMessageSent ?? '',
                );

                chatCards.add(chatCard);
              }
              return Visibility(
                visible: checkIfOnAnyChats(),
                child: Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: chatCards,
                  ),
                ),

              );
            }
          }
        ),
```

This is what the '`checkIfOnAnyChats()`' Future looks like:

```
  Future<bool> checkIfOnAnyChats() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

    final QuerySnapshot result = await _firestore
        .collection('chats')
        .where('members', arrayContains: _username)
        .getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;

    if(documents.length > 0) {
      setState(() {
        return true;
      });
    }else{
      setState(() {
        return false;
      });
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to assign this value to the 'visible' boolean but it doesn't work because it is a **Future bool** and not a normal bool.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `bool` that returned from a Future, you need to use FutureBuilder;

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _firestore.collection('chats').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    } else {
      final chats = snapshot.data.documents;
      List<ChatCard> chatCards = [];
      for (var chat in chats) {
        final String nameOfChat = chat.data['name'];
        final String lastMessageSent = chat.data['lastMessageSent'];
        final List members = chat.data['members'];

        final ChatCard chatCard = ChatCard(
          nameOfChat: nameOfChat ?? '',
          lastMessageSent: lastMessageSent ?? '',
        );

        chatCards.add(chatCard);
      }
      return FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: checkIfOnAnyChats(),
        builder: (context, fSnapshot) {
          if (fSnapshot.hasData)
            return Visibility(
              visible: fSnapshot.data,
              child: Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: chatCards,
                ),
              ),
            );
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      );
    }
  },
),
```

and you don't need to use setState inside Future functions;

```
Future<bool> checkIfOnAnyChats() async {
  FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

  final QuerySnapshot result = await _firestore
      .collection('chats')
      .where('members', arrayContains: _username)
      .getDocuments();
  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;

  return documents.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still displays the ChatCard widget even if the user is not on the members array